# Passing a string variable to pandas dataframe giving KeyError:

Tags: python, pandas

The below is the code that i am using to create a dataframe based on a condition. It is working fine when the value of the variable(my_var) is passed directly. But when the variable name is used pandas is giving a key error. Is there a way to overcome this issue ?

```py
##df4 and df3 are pandas dataframe

print(my_var)

Output : (df3['Division Code'] == 0)|(df3['Division Code'] ==10)|(df3['Division Code'] ==20)|(df3['Division Code'] ==30)

df4=df3[(df3['Division Code'] == 0)|(df3['Division Code'] ==10)|(df3['Division Code'] ==20)|(df3['Division Code'] ==30)]

Output: Working fine and no errors

df4=df3[my_var]

Output: KeyError: "(df3['Division Code'] == 0)|(df3['Division Code'] ==10)|(df3['Division Code'] ==20)|(df3['Division Code'] ==30)"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that `my_var` is a string variable which contains `"(df3['Division Code'] == 0)|(df3['Division Code'] ==10)|(df3['Division Code'] ==20)|(df3['Division Code'] ==30)"` Because it is a string, your DataFrame is looking for a column, which has this (weird) name.

The better way would be defining `my_var` as:

```py
my_var = df3['Division Code'].isin((0,10,20,30))
df4=df3[my_var]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Daniel Wlazlo.. The solution provided by you has worked.I have spend quite some time to resolve the issue on my own but none worked. Thanks again